# Flutter blurred keyboard style

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a question, how to make a transparent blurred background on a keyboard, like this one in the telegram app: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fgnG.png)

By default, the keyboard has a plain gray background.
Is it possible to achieve this result in flutter? Any help would be appreciated!